# Why doob's optional stopping time theorem does not have conditional sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

I would appreciate it if someone can point out where I am misunderstanding.

The statments I am seeing prior to optinal stopping time theorem is below,

1. For a supermartingale, $E[X_m|F_n]\leq X_n$ for $m\geq n$
2. For a submartingale, $E[X_m|F_n]\geq X_n$ for $m\geq n$
3. Hence, For a martingale, $E[X_m|F_n]= X_n$ for $m\geq n$

I saw that the proof of 1. and 2., come from the definition of martingales as below

$E[X_m|F_n]=E[E[X_m|F_{m-1}]|F_n]\leq E[X_{m-1}|F_n]\leq...\leq E[X_n|F_n]\leq X_n$ as $X_n\in F_n$

and 3. comes because martingale is super/sub martingale.

a) Optional Stopping Theorem: For a supermartingale and a stopping time $T$, $E[X_{T\wedge n}]\leq E[X_0]$, same for submartingale and martingale. s.t. $E[X_{T\wedge n}]=E[X_0]$, with some bounded condition on $T$ and such..

I am having trouble understanding a).
I think it makes sense if it was $E[X_{T\wedge n}|F_0]\leq E[X_0]$, Directly following from 1, by putting expecation on both side.

But it doesn't have the conditional sigma algebra $F_0$. Then how is it possible?

Simpler example I saw but don't understand is, not even a stopping time but a fixed number $i>0$, $E[X_i]=E[X_0]$. Again, When it does not have conditional sigma algebra $F_0$, how is it possible?

Comment: Your statements 1, 2, and 3 are wrong.

Comment: @CélioAugusto I modified it. Would you mind checking it again please??

Comment: You are basically asking other MSE members to match your definitions with those that can be found [everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#Submartingales,_supermartingales,_and_relationship_to_harmonic_functions).

Comment: @KurtG. I'm sorry if my question seems trivial for you but I'm just confused. The link you shared seems to define sub/super martingale and 1.2.3. I wrote down is just the definition. But those definitions also have conditional sigma algebra. I am confused about statements like "for a fixed number $>0,$ $X$ being martingale, $[_i]=[_0]$", which do not have conditional sigma algebra and where it is coming from..

Comment: I am confused about what you are asking. Perhaps it helps to know that from the inequality $$\mathbb E[X_m|{\cal F}_n]\ge X_n$$ it follows that $$\mathbb E[X_m]\ge \mathbb E[X_n]$$ by taking the expectation on both sides. Same holds for the other inequality and for the equality.